# Drool Workbench : How to call User defined static Java Method from Drool Rule

Tags: java, drools, drools-guvnor

Actually I know how to call static method from Drool by writing manually DRL. But Right now i am exploring Drool Workbench for increasing productivity.

I have static java method which will accepting two Parameter. I have already import that java class in rule.

I only need list of steps which help me to add Java method call in my rule from Drool Workbench.

Comment: Do you have some source code to show?

Comment: I need steps using which i am able to call Java Method from Guided Rule of Workbench.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an option "Call method on " in the `Then` part of the Drools workbench.

Step 1: Add the DataObject (ex: SampleDataObject) in the `When` part so you will have `There is a SampleDataObject`

Step 2: Now clicking on the '+' icon for the `Then` part, you will have an option `Call method on SampleDataObject`. Click on it and it will show you list of the methods in your data object. You can select that method and pass your parameters.